# Hibernmate + Postgres dosent create tables on first run

Tags: java, database, postgresql, hibernate, postgresql-9.3

I have a small app and i want hibernate to create tables if donst exist. I have all the annotation needed(i think) and mi hibernate.cfg.xml completed, but when i run a test to see if the dao method are correct hibernate show me an exception saying that the relations dont exist. When i check the database there is no tables.

I want to know if the is a way to make hibernate to create the tables automatically or if i have to add some new code or properties to my code.

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <!-- SQL Dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Connection Settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tour_bi</property>
        <property name="connection.username">xxx</property>
        <property name="connection.password">xxx</property>


        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Update database on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2dll.auto">create</property>



        <!-- Annotated entity classes -->
        <mapping class="domain.Car_Type"/>
        <mapping class="domain.Car"/>
        <mapping class="domain.Client"/>
        <mapping class="domain.Country"/>
        <mapping class="domain.Guide"/>
        <mapping class="domain.Imagen"/>
        <mapping class="domain.Languaje"/>
        <mapping class="domain.Province"/>
        <mapping class="domain.Stop"/>
        <mapping class="domain.System"/>
        <mapping class="domain.Tour_Type"/>
        <mapping class="domain.System"/>
        <mapping class="domain.Tour"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The database exist under public schema

this is my test class

```
 public class TestDB {

    @Test
    public void crudTest() {

        Configuration configuration= new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        SessionFactory factory=configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session=factory.openSession();

        createCarTYpe(session);

        createCar(session);
        readCar(session);
        updateCar(session);
        readCar(session);
        deleteCar(session);
        readCar(session);
        session.close();
    }

    private void deleteCar(Session session) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Eliminando Auto");
        Car car=(Car)session.get(Car.class,1);
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(car);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    private void updateCar(Session session) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Actualizando Auto");
        Car car=(Car)session.get(Car.class,1);
        car.setCant_people(10);
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(car);
        session.getTransaction().commit();      
    }

    private void createCar(Session session) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Creando Autos");
        Car carA=new Car();
        carA.setCant_people(5);
        carA.setCar_type(Car_TypeDAO.getCarType(0));
        carA.setTours(new ArrayList<Tour>());

        Car carB=new Car();
        carB.setCant_people(5);
        carB.setCar_type(Car_TypeDAO.getCarType(0));
        carB.setTours(new ArrayList<Tour>());

        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(carA);
        session.save(carB);
        session.getTransaction().commit();              
    }

    private void readCar(Session session) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Query q=session.createQuery("select car from car");
        ArrayList<Car> cars = (ArrayList<Car>) q.list();
        System.out.println("Leyendo Autos");
        for(Car c:cars) {
            System.out.println(c.toString());
        }
    }


    private void createCarTYpe(Session session) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Creando Autos");
        Car_Type carA=new Car_Type();
        carA.setActive(true);
        carA.setType("Deportivo");


        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(carA);
        session.getTransaction().commit();              
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

and this is one of my models

```
@Entity
 @Table(name="car_type")
 public class Car_Type {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="_id", unique = true)
private long _id;

@Column(name="active")
private boolean active;

@Column(name="type")
private String type;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "car_type")
private Car car;

public Car_Type(boolean active, String type,Car car) {
    super();
    this.active = active;
    this.type = type;
    this.car=car;
}

public Car_Type() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public long get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public void set_id(long _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public boolean isActive() {
    return active;
}

public void setActive(boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}


public Car getCar() {
    return car;
}

public void setCar(Car car) {
    this.car = car;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Car_Type [active=" + active + ", type=" + type + "]";
}
}
```

this is the log in console

```
 log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
   06:06:29.838 [main] INFO org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - Hibernate Commons Annotations         3.2.0.Final
   06:06:31.101 [main] INFO org.hibernate.validator.util.Version - Hibernate Validator 4.0.2.GA
   06:06:31.105 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.engine.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator -       ValidationMessages not found. Delegating to org.hibernate.validator.ValidationMessages
   06:06:31.110 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver -    Found javax.persistence.PersistenceUtil on classpath.
   06:06:31.112 [main] INFO org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver -    Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
   06:06:31.116 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.xml.ValidationXmlParser - No META-INF/validation.xml found. Using annotation based configuration only
   06:06:31.196 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.engine.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator - ValidationMessages not found. Delegating to org.hibernate.validator.ValidationMessages
   06:06:31.196 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver -    Found javax.persistence.PersistenceUtil on classpath.
   06:06:31.197 [main] INFO org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver -    Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
   06:06:31.203 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.xml.ValidationXmlParser - No META-   INF/validation.xml found. Using annotation based configuration only
   Creando Autos
   Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
   Hibernate: insert into car_type (active, type, _id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

there is nothing saying that hibernate is creating any tables, its goes rigth to create objects
and in my test log:

```
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ERROR: no existe la relación «car_type»
  Position: 13
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2849)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3290)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1081)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at test.TestDB.createCarTYpe(TestDB.java:98)
    at test.TestDB.crudTest(TestDB.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:305)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:365)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:330)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:328)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:65)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:292)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:305)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: no existe la relación «car_type»
  Position: 13
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2505)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2241)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:310)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:447)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:368)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:158)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
    ... 43 more
```

Im using tomcat server 9. Did i need to update web.xml on my tomcat?

[this is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pz7fY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Update this setting:

```
 <property name="hbm2dll.auto">create</property>
```

to:

```
 <property name="hbm2dll.auto">update</property>
```

[What are the possible values of the Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto configuration and what do they do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/what-are-the-possible-values-of-the-hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-configuration-and-wha)

Comment: thanks for the answer. i already tried whit update but nothing happend